# Getting error GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am making and ecommerce shopping application using JSON Parsing and using local server xapmm. There are various categories on my app like Mobile, Laptop, Grocery, Home appliance etc. There is no error while building but when I run the app after testing few categories and when I reach to 4-5 category I get this error:

> E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1

[image: this is where I am getting the error, at line 44]

Answer (score 1):

That's not your error, it's the one 29 seconds later that says `FATAL EXCEPTION`!

The issue is on line 44. You are trying to get the `position`th element of the `img` array, but it does not exist (`img[position]`).